# HTTPS routing suddenly stopped working in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my Grails `2.5.1` application , i was using a filter to use `HTTPS` with some controllers , everything was working fine but suddenly this filter is not working any more .

Filter :

```
def filters = {
    all(controller:'checkout', action:'onlinePayment') {
        before = {

            if (!request.isSecure() /*&& !Environment.isDevelopmentMode()*/) {
                def url = "https://" + request.serverName+':8443' + request.forwardURI
                println "in filter"
                redirect(url: url, permanent: true)
                return false
            }
        }
        after = { Map model ->
        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `checkout` page :

[image]
Also i found that no requests came to the filter as `in filter` was not printed out, is there something i need to check to fix this issue rather than this filter

Comment: Can you explain the changes you did? It's odd when you say 'suddenly' it didn't work.

Comment: @Quchie , i didn;t change anything in the filter , this why i said `suddenly`

Comment: any other advice ?